Can you identify this inverted slope piece?
Need help identifying a piece, please.




This is a Mega Construx Slope 2x2x4 Inverted ( MA15488 )
In Black it appears in Stage Fright Monster High (2016):

It could also be from another set.

Thank you for your help!

@Edward Please do not add a comment on an answer to say "Thank you", but accept the answer as outlined here in the help center.
